# Make hash password laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have problem to my apps this input password hash.

```
    $simpan['password']=Request::input('password');
```

how make hash in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options

Call make method on Hash facade 
`Hash::make('string_here')`

Or use global helper function `bcrypt('string_here')`

Example:

```
//Hash facade example
$simpan['password']= Hash::make(Request::input('password'));

//bcrypt global helper function
$simpan['password']= bcrypt(Request::input('password'));
```

Resource:

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/hashing

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel we can handle it a very intelligent and efficient way by using Mutators in Model Class.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];    


    // Password hassing by default to all new users,
    public function setPasswordAttribute($pass)
    {
        // here you can make any opration as you like
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($pass);
    }

}
```

now you don't have to do manually password hashing every time
just store user in table by create or any other method

```
$created_user = User::create(request()->all());
```